# Crazy gem and bundle trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubymine

I'm working on a shared Rails project and have some trouble with installing it on my pc. I opened the project in RubyMine and got an output error like this:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... no
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC() in time.h... no
checking for clockid_t in time.h... no
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... no
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... no
getaddrinfo required
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
    --with-rtlib
    --without-rtlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.7.4/ext/kgio/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing kgio (2.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.7.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try to run the server, he complains that some gems were not installed. The most annoying thing is that he don't want to install those gems (see above).

Is there anyone who knows something that can help me?

Thanks in advance...

Edit: mkmf.log

```
have_macro: checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration   -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:8:3: error: #error 
conftest.c:9:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '>>' token
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <time.h>
 6: /*top*/
 7: #ifndef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
 8: # error
 9: >>>>>> CLOCK_MONOTONIC undefined <<<<<<
10: #endif
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC() in time.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:53: error: 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:8:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <time.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))CLOCK_MONOTONIC; return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC'
C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoSUpHu.o: In function `t':
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\kgio-2.7.4\ext\kgio/conftest.c:8: undefined reference to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <time.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: int t() { CLOCK_MONOTONIC(); return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_type: checking for clockid_t in time.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration   -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:8:19: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'conftest_type'
conftest.c:9:24: error: 'conftest_type' undeclared here (not in a function)
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <time.h>
6: 
7: /*top*/
8: typedef clockid_t conftest_type;
9: int conftestval[sizeof(conftest_type)?1:-1];
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lrt  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:53: error: 'clock_gettime' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:8:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <time.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))clock_gettime; return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lrt  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_gettime'
c:/ruby193/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <time.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: int t() { clock_gettime(); return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for t_open() in -lnsl... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lnsl  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:7:53: error: 't_open' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:7:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))t_open; return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lnsl  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:7:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 't_open'
c:/ruby193/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lnsl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: int t() { t_open(); return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for socket() in -lsocket... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lsocket  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
c:/ruby193/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsocket
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))socket; return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lsocket  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:7:1: error: too few arguments to function 'socket'
c:\ruby193\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/winsock2.h:553:35: note: declared here
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: int t() { socket(); return 0; }
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for poll() in poll.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c:5:18: fatal error: poll.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <poll.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))poll; return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c:5:18: fatal error: poll.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <poll.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: int t() { poll(); return 0; }
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     printf("%p", &t);
13:   }
14: 
15:   return 0;
16: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c:6:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <sys/types.h>
 6: #include <sys/socket.h>
 7: #include <netdb.h>
 8: 
 9: /*top*/
10: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))getaddrinfo; return 0; }
11: int main(int argc, char **argv)
12: {
13:   if (argc > 1000000) {
14:     printf("%p", &t);
15:   }
16: 
17:   return 0;
18: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=1-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c:6:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <sys/types.h>
 6: #include <sys/socket.h>
 7: #include <netdb.h>
 8: 
 9: /*top*/
10: int t() { getaddrinfo(); return 0; }
11: int main(int argc, char **argv)
12: {
13:   if (argc > 1000000) {
14:     printf("%p", &t);
15:   }
16: 
17:   return 0;
18: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: are those gems really installed or not?

Comment: No, I get the error while I'm trying to install those gems...

Comment: you have to install the ruby dev kit for windows

Comment: It is installed. I have no trouble with running another project on the same server...

Comment: provide also `mkmf.log`

Comment: you have improperly installed headers

Comment: And what does that mean/ How do I solve that?

Comment: I don;t know for windows, try to do the same steps as for the working project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution to this problem. The problem was that some gems not work in a Windows environment. So, this problem is solvable by just running the project on a Linux server...